# Android Mapview: Control ordering of multiple types of OverlayItems?

Tags: android, android-mapview, itemizedoverlay

I have searched for a while on this problem but have come up trumps.

I have a simple mapview that makes use of custom overlay items on a [ManagedOverlay](http://code.google.com/p/mapview-overlay-manager/), let's call them `redOverlayItem` and `blueOverlayItem`. All the ManagedOverlay does is query my database for a set of locations of varying types and then place them on a map asynchronously.

My managed overlay works fine, however I can't seem to be able to control the "z" ordering. For instance, sometimes I have `redOverlayItem` 's covering `blueOverlayItem` 's and vice versa, where I really just want `redOverlayItem` 's to be on top.

I've exhausted my ideas on how to fix this. How can I control ordering of multiple types of overlay items?

Answer (score 1):

Alright guys, I figured it out.

In your Overlay, you need to override getIndexToDraw

```
//Overriding to return add order rather than latitude order.
protected int getIndexToDraw(int drawingOrder) {
    return drawingOrder;
}
```

Rather than call super.getIndexToDraw(int), which returns items ordered by latitude value, all I'm doing now is returning the order in which they are added. Then all I do for my array of overlays is sort them accordingly (I'm using Rob Carmick's [BeanComparator](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/23/bean-comparator/), but you could use any sorting function really)

```
BeanComparator bc = new BeanComparator(CustomOverlayItem.class, "getIsRed");
Collections.sort(overlayItemsArray, bc);
```